# Connecting to MySQL via a batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file, cmd

I've configured a batch file to check a web hosted db every 30 seconds or so to see if the value in one field has been set to 1. I'm happy with how that works and the results come through fine.

However one issue I have is that once in a while the script is unable to connect to the SQL server. When this happens my script errors out and the batch file stops.

The connection line I am using is:

```
mysql --host=xxx.xxx.xxx --port=3306 --force --user=wmc --password=xxxxxxxxx --database=xxx < xxx.sql
```

The sql file at the end contains the commands I want to run. I read some documentation that said the --force should make the script continue after an error but it still errors out when it can't connect to the SQL server. Is there any way I can trap this error?

Comment: how about checking error code in batch and perform a loop

Comment: I think I've found the reason that the --force parameter wasn't working on the sql command. I'd put a space between -- and force

Comment: what does force do, just block !? Oh and btw, Welcome to The Stack, and thanks for sharing !

Comment: according to the documentation force makes the mysql application ignore the error message produced when it can't connect to the sql. While for some people this is not idea, in my instance this is fine as I am creating a log entry on the sql server, but I am also logging to a local txt file. Thanks for the welcome

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem seems to be error handling. I would personally change my script to be able to detect a failure and then retry until successful.

### Quick Test

A rough test I did on my own system to check error level pseudo environmental variable:

**Test.bat**

```
 D:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --force --user=root2 --password= --database=saasplex < test.sql
    echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%

    D:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --force --user=root --password= --database=saasplex < test.sql
    echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%
```

**Console Result**

```
F:\_MBAK_DOCUMENTS\_OTHER_PROJECTS\STACKEXCHANGE\August6>mysqlErrorDetect.bat

F:\_MBAK_DOCUMENTS\_OTHER_PROJECTS\STACKEXCHANGE\August6>D:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --force --user=root2 --password= --database=saasplex  0<test.sql
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'saasplex'

F:\_MBAK_DOCUMENTS\_OTHER_PROJECTS\STACKEXCHANGE\August6>echo Exit Code is 1
Exit Code is 1

F:\_MBAK_DOCUMENTS\_OTHER_PROJECTS\STACKEXCHANGE\August6>D:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --force --user=root --password= --database=saasplex  0<test.sql
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
1
1

F:\_MBAK_DOCUMENTS\_OTHER_PROJECTS\STACKEXCHANGE\August6>echo Exit Code is 0
```

### Batch Script with Retries

```
set tries=10
:loop

    D:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --force --user=root --password= --database=saasplex < test.sql

if errorlevel 1 (
   set /a tries=tries-1
   if %tries%==0 goto exitloop
   goto loop
)

:exitloop
```